# Agregar nuevos campos en models.py en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo el siguiente modelo en models.py:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    link = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Videos'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

Quiero agregar dos nuevos atributos:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
number_of_searches = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

El modelo quedaría así:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    link = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    number_of_searches = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Videos'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando `python manage.py makemigrations` me dice que no hay cambios para aplicar. Cuando borro las dos lineas y vuelvo a correr el comando me tira en pantalla:

```
blog/migrations/0006_auto_20170102_1904.py:
    - Remove field created from videos
    - Remove field number_of_searches from videos
```

Cuando las vuelvo a agregar me dice:

```
blog/migrations/0007_auto_20170102_1905.py:
    - Add field created to videos
    - Add field number_of_searches to videos
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el `python manage.py migrate` me muestra el siguiente error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'created'; check
>   that column/key exists")

Como si existiera el campo. No encuentro solución, les agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Primero debes descartar que las columnas no existan de verdad, para eso puedes acceder a la base de datos directamente o graficamente de acuerdo a donde estes, ya sea MySQL o Postgress, otra forma, es crear los campos, sin crear las migraciones, y desde la shell acceder a `Videos.objects.first().created` a ver si tira error, si tira error, el campo no existe, si no tira error, es que ya existe... con cualquiera de las dos, comenta que sucede para seguirte ayudando

Comment: Hola Germán! Ya probé desde mysql workbench y ambos campos no existen

Comment: Intenta esto, cuando te sale que ha creado los campos que en tu ejemplo es la migracion 0007, entonces primero mira `./manage.py showmigrations` a ver si la 0006 o 0007 sale chuleadas, luego borra la 0006 (se supone esta es donde dice que borrará los campos), y modifica la 0007 haciendo que la dependencia sea la 0005, comentame los resultados de cada paso, por ultimo, haces el migrate

Comment: Gracias! Voy a intentar! Solo que no se como se borra una migración y que consecuencias tendría

Comment: Si la migración no está realizada, simplemente borra el archivo que creó la migracion, de lo contrario haz `./manage.py migrate nombre_del_app 0005` y eso retrocede la migracion, lo que no estoy seguro es qué tanto soporte tenga ese comando en bases de datos de MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucioné el problema de la siguiente forma:

1. Elimine la carpeta (no sin antes hacer un backup de ella) `migrations` dentro de la carpeta de mi app.
2. `python manage.py makemigrations *miApp*`
3. `python manage.py migrate *miApp*`